# In android , how to save content of an arraylist

Tags: android, navigation, arraylist, savestate

I have to consider saving the contents of an arraylist when navigating to an from the activity holding  it and be able to add and delete. Any idea how to do this without making use of the database.

Comment: Would need some more specifics, is it persisted even when the app is closed?

Answer (score 1):

You can use shared preferences instead of database. In shared preferences, you can store data persistently as key-value pairs.

I strongly suggest you to read this (it's not too long):
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Answer (score 1):

If it is only a connection between 2 activities and not the whole app, I would consider to make use of an Intent.

You can put all kinds of extras to an Intent (also arrays) and connect the Intent to the startActivity(). In the new Activity you can unfold the extras and use them.